# Filtered non-clustered Index abnormal behaivior

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have a table that created some filtered non-clustered on some columns such:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Sh_Esh] ON [dbo].[My_Tbl] 
(
    [City_Code] ASC,
[Sh_Esh] ASC
)
WHERE ([Sh_Bod]=(0) AND [Noe_Fa]=(0))
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

and:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Kho] ON [dbo].[My_Tbl] 
(
[City_Code] ASC,
[Kho] ASC
)
WHERE ([Sh_Bod]=(0) AND [Sh_Esh]=(0) AND [Noe_Fa]=(1))
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I create this indexes on my table with no error but when I want to add a new column I get this error:

```
'My_Tbl' table
- Unable to create index 'IX_Sh_Esh'.  
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'My_Tbl' and the index name 'IX_Sh_Esh'. The duplicate key value is (3, 0).
```

The statement has been terminated.

my table data is:

[image]

According to first Index because the rows No. 1 and No. 4 does not satisfy the where cluase should not create index on them.Why I get the above error?

thanks

**EDIT 1)** :

there is Interesting point.If I delete that index and add the Column(s) then ReCreate that Index,the index create with no error.STRANGE!!!!

Comment: There's only 6 rows in the table?

Comment: No,There is more but error just show (3,0) for duplicated

Comment: So did you do a `SELECT * FROM dbo.My_Tbl WHERE City_Code = 3 AND Sh_Esh = 0` to see if there were other rows?

Comment: please see `Where` clause for first index.`City_Code = 3 AND Sh_Esh = 0` rows should not participate in unique index because `Sh_Bod<>0`

Comment: please read my comment before responding.  Run the query and see how many rows you get.

Comment: there is 2 rows with that condition

Comment: So,What is your idea with return 2 rows by that query?

Comment: Do you execute `alter table command` to add a column or do you use SSMS table designer when you add the column? If you use SSMS, what does the change script look like?

Comment: I use SSMS to add a new column.It does not add a new column so script of table not changed

Comment: In SSMS, after you added the column but **before you click save** you can generate the change script that SSMS will run to add the column. You find it under menu `Table Designer - Generate Change Script`. If you could copy and past that to the question it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can drop the index and then add the data, then recreate the index is because creating an index does not check existing data, just data that you are trying to insert/update.

You're not getting the error because its a filtered index, you're getting it because its a unique index and you're trying to add duplicate values to the table's column that the unique index is on. That's the beaty of them! If you need duplicate data don't make the index unique.

Comment: Thanks but please read my question fully.I'm not trying to add data I want to add a new column with current correct data

Comment: `create unique index` does check existing data when the index is created.